# Facing this error while doing npm run build

Tags: typescript

While running npm run build on the graphQL files, I am suddenly facing these errors:

error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'content-disposition'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'http-errors'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'nodemailer'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'qs'.

Here is my package.json

```
    "name": "b2e-graphql-api",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
        "build:dev": "nest build && cp -R schema/ dist && cp package.json dist",
        "build:stage": "nest build && cp -R schema/ dist && cp package.json dist",
        "build:qa": "nest build && cp -R schema/ dist && cp package.json dist",
        "build": "nest build && cp -R schema/ dist",
        "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
        "start": "nest start",
        "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
        "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
        "start:prod": "node dist/main",
        "codegen": "graphql-codegen",
        "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
        "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
        "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@nestjs/common": "^6.10.14",
        "@nestjs/core": "^6.10.14",
        "@nestjs/graphql": "^6.6.2",
        "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.10.14",
        "apollo-datasource-rest": "^0.8.0",
        "apollo-server": "^2.11.0",
        "dataloader": "2.0.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "graphql": "^14.6.0",
        "graphql-codegen": "^0.4.0",
        "graphql-tools": "^4.0.7",
        "html-minifier": "^4.0.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mobile-detect": "^1.4.4",
        "npm": "^7.5.6",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
        "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
        "winston": "^3.3.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.19.2",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.17.0",
        "@nestjs/cli": "^6.13.2",
        "@nestjs/schematics": "^6.8.1",
        "@nestjs/testing": "^6.10.14",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
        "@types/jest": "25.1.2",
        "@types/node": "^13.1.6",
        "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.2.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
        "jest": "^24.9.0",
        "prettier": "^1.18.2",
        "supertest": "^4.0.2",
        "ts-jest": "25.2.0",
        "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
        "ts-node": "^8.6.0",
        "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
        "typescript": "^3.7.4"
    },
    "jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "json",
            "ts"
        ],
        "rootDir": "src",
        "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
        },
        "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
        "testEnvironment": "node"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must install the type definition. To achieve that

```
npm install --save @types/http-errors
npm install --save @types/nodemailer
npm install --save @types/qs
npm install --save @types/content-disposition
```

in your project folder, if you are using npm.

Comment: Have you tried the solution? did it work?